# Insert GUID into SQL Table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using ASP.Net/C# and I have a form that allows people to add information into a table and along with it I want to collect the Current Users GUID and insert it.

I have a field setup (UserID) as a unique identifier and I have the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
    Guid temp = (Guid)(Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey);
    Guid @currentUserID = temp;
}

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
SqlCommand cmd;

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Accom (UserID) values('" + @currentUserID + "')", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

I basically want to link the variable to the Database any idea how as the above gives errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Guid @currentUserID = temp;
```

You are defining a variable `currentUserID`  in local scope - you must save this variable in the `Session` so you can access it in the `Button1_Click` method:

```
Session["UserId"] = currentUserID;
```

Now you can retrieve it in  `Button1_Click`:

```
Guid currentUserID = (Guid)Session["UserId"];
```

Also the @ is not needed nor should it be there, you only should need it if you want to define variables with a name that matches a C# keyword - this is bad style anyway. Also you want to put the `SqlConnection` specific code all within the button click handler - otherwise this variable is instantiated evertime the page loads, not just when the button click handler is used. Finally you also want to use `SqlParameters` instead of strings in your SQL insert statement.

**Edit:**

As @pst pointed out, the more "ASP.NET way" would be to just use an instance variable

```
Guid currentUserID;
```

that you declare as part of the class, not within a method - then you can use this variable throughout the page. This means however, the user id will not be available on other pages (with a session it could be retrieved through the life time of the session on any page).

Comment: Thanks Mate worked Brilliantly :) Thanks to everyone else too :)

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use Session here instead of just a member variable (setup in Page Load)?

Comment: @pst: Yes I suppose that's more idiomatic for ASP.NET - I've been "off the hook" for too long - I will edit this in.

Answer (score 4):

You should never insert values directly into a SQL statement like that, no matter what type they are, as that opens you up to a [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack. Instead, you should use parameters in your query, through which `System.Guid` values will be automatically translated to the SQL Server `uniqueidentifier` type. This is how I would do it:

```
Guid currentUserId = (Guid)(Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey);
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("..."))
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Accom (UserID) VALUES (@UserID)";
    var param = command.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
    param.Value = currentuserId;
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if SQL server supports GUID as a datatype, in MysQL I would go with a char, but that is not important, just a comment. The important part is that in the method:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Accom (UserID) values('" + @currentUserID + "')", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

You don't specify the actual value for @currentUserID
you must rewrite it to something like:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Accom (UserID) values(@currentUserID)", con);
    //this are the important lines that I'm talking about
    param.ParameterName = "@currentUserID";
    param.Value         = valueOfUserId;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: "I dont know if SQL server supports GUID as a datatype" - it does, it's called a uniqueidentifier

Comment: I'm holding off on the -1 because I think it's trying to use place-holders. However, as it is now, it's just broken. Fix the SqlCommand text.

Answer (score 0):

In the original code above the `currentUser` variable is unused.  Also if the user is not logged on the call to `Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name)` will return a null reference and trying to retrieve ProviderUserKey code will throw a NullReferenceException.  It would be better to have something along these lines;

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    MembershipUser currentUser;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (null != currentUser)
        {
            Guid currentUserID = currentUser.ProviderUserKey;
            // database code here
        }
    }
}
```